# Parsing Operator and Operand

Tags: java

OK, so I am writing a console calculator and I am stuck.  I have everything working but the actual part where a user enters say 3*2+8 and then the program tell the user the answer.  I can, however, enter a single number like 3 and it return 3.0. I think I need to parse the expression entered by the user to perform the math.  Can you help me?

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = ""; // initalize the string
        boolean isOn = true; // used for the while loop...when false, the program will exit.
        String exitCommand = "Exit"; // exit command



        System.out.print("Enter a math problem"); // dummy test
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        //input = keyboard.nextLine();
        String[] token = input.split(("(?<=[-+*/])|(?=[-+*/])"));
        while (isOn) {
            for (int i = 0; i < token.length; i++) {
                //System.out.println(token[i]);
                Double d = Double.parseDouble(keyboard.nextLine()); //This causes an error
                //String[] token = d.split(("(?<=[-+*/])|(?=[-+*/])"));
                //input = keyboard.nextLine();

                if (input.equalsIgnoreCase(exitCommand)) {
                    // if the user enters exit(ignored case) the boolean goes to false, closing the application
                    isOn = false;
                }

               System.out.print(token[0] + d); // shows the math problem(which would by the end of the coding should show the
                //answer to the entered math problem.

            }


        }
    }
    public void validOperator() {
        ArrayList<String> operator = new ArrayList<String>();
        operator.add("+");
        operator.add("-");
        operator.add("*");
        operator.add("/");

    }
    public void validOperands(){
        ArrayList<String> operand = new ArrayList<String>();
        operand.add("0");
        operand.add("1");
        operand.add("2");
        operand.add("3");
        operand.add("4");
        operand.add("5");
        operand.add("6");
        operand.add("7");
        operand.add("8");
        operand.add("9");
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Aside: make the exitCommand String `final`

Comment: Why not remove all spaces and turn into input into `char[]`? Then processing should be easier. Find an operand (based on order of operations) and reduce the array (or maybe array list is better) by executing it on its two operands.

Comment: Thank you, I fixed it on my desktop version :).

Comment: How would I go about doing that?

Comment: That would involve turning the operands into `ints`. Instead of reducing array, you might be better off having a double[] answer that keeps track of some of the parts of the equation and stuff... Idk. This wouldnt work if the input contains numbers larger than one char unless you design it too.

Comment: Assignment requirement is a string array list :-/

Comment: Where you have the initial token, do `char[] inputChars = keyboard.nextLine().toCharArray();` i think. Its a String method; your ides code completion should find it. To remove the spaces, you can loop through and fix the array.

Comment: @wwe9112 your code does not agree with what you try to do. you just splited what you get and parse double it in one variable? I do not get it at all\

Comment: All I want to do is take a basic math problem a user would enter and perform the math.  The requirement was to have eveerything in a string, split it, and parse it as a double then perform the arithmetic.

Answer (score 1):

You do not take in account the precedence of math operators. And what if a user will use brackets, like `(2 + 3) * 4 + 5/2`

I recommend to convert the initial expression to the [postfix notation](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PostfixNotation) before evaluating it.

Here is [the example with explanation for C++](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/278696-using-stack-to-convert-prefix-to-post-fix/), I think it will be easy to apply this explanation to the java language.

Comment: And if OP doesnt know C++?

Comment: He knows java, it is enough to understand the sample provided.

Comment: I get where the walkthrough is going, however I don't really GET it if that makes sense.  I don't really know a lot of Java at all lol. Something this small should not be causing me two days of headache.